# Remove cookie problems JS-COOKIE

Tags: javascript, cookies, js-cookie

JS Cookies remove cookie, undefined

Hi Guys, I have trying to remove a cookie from a domain but I can't, the console return undefined.

When I log in the cookie is set up in .dev.books.com but after that the URL change to platform.dev.books.com and keep the same cookies.  The name of the cookie I want to remove is bookId, here is my try:

```
Cookies.set('bookId', ' ');
```

But instead to change the cookie value, create a new one with the domain platform.dev.books.com

If I use

```
Cookie.remove('bookId')
```

the console return undefined

Thanks, any help will be helpful

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can unset cookie and set the expire header time to a past date

```
document.cookie = "bookId=; expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 UTC";
```

Comment: when I do this `document.cookie = "bookId =; expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 UTC";` the console return `"bookId=; expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 UTC"` but doesn't update the value or remove the cookie :/

Answer (score 6):

```
Cookie.remove('bookId')
```

^^This wont work. You always need to include the relative path of the current page. Like this:

```
Cookies.remove('name', { path: '/', domain: '.yourdomain.com' })
```

The '/' stands for the root page.

Answer (score 3):

It really depends on the environment, you may have to set the domain attribute that matches the cookie domain stored in the browser

Cookies.remove('name', { domain: 'subdomain.site.com' });

You may encounter mismatch domain if the website is hosted behind a reverse proxy or load-balancer.

Best way to be sure to check the http header with fiddler.

Answer (score 0):

Delete a cookie valid to the path of the current page:

```
Cookies.set('name', 'value', { path: '' })
Cookies.remove('name') // fail!
Cookies.remove('name', { path: '' }) // removed!
```

IMPORTANT! When deleting a cookie and you're not relying on the default attributes, you must pass the exact same path and domain attributes that were used to set the cookie:

```
Cookies.remove('name', { path: '', domain: '.yourdomain.com' })

Note: Removing a nonexistent cookie neither raises any exception nor returns any value.
```

I'll advice you always try to go through the readme of any package you use, thank me latter, lol.  https://www.npmjs.com/package/js-cookie